# How to set property value of JsonElement in JsonDocument .NET CORE>?

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-core

I have a this code:

```
var req = new RestRequest("admin/wireless", Method.POST);
req.AddQueryParameter("form", "wireless_2g");
req.AddParameter("operation", "read", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
var res = await restClient.ExecuteAsync(req);

var jdoc = JsonDocument.Parse(res.Content);
var jprop = jdoc.RootElement.GetProperty("enable");
```

I want to alter the value **jprop** to true and send the request back to server/router, how do I do this without creating a new Object... there is no method e.g: `jdoc.RootElement.GetProperty("enable").SetValue()`

thank you in advance

Comment: Any chance of providing a [mcve]? This feels like a fairly easy one to provide a complete console app for, so we can easily validate any suggestion. (No need to involve web parts at all.)